# Using a Computer PSU for its 12V output for high wattage loads

Tags: power-supply, led, 12v

I'm looking to install some LED light bars (primarily designed for use on off-road cars) as fixed outdoor lighting on my property.  I see they have models that use up to 700+ watts of power (for crazy amounts of light, like 78,000+ lumens) at 12VDC:

[image]

If I were to use a 800W+ computer power supply to power the light bar, could the power supply handle a 700W load through a single molex connector?  I understand usually the loads are spread over multiple connectors on multiple 12V rails.  I'm not sure if I can handle a single 700W load.  Should I connect it to both rails simultaneously?

Comment: 700 Watts at 12 volts as 58+ amps. A single molex connector pin is rated at, I believe 5 amps. So, no, you cannot use a single (or even a few) connectors.

Comment: BTW, questions about using devices is off-topic here.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Will look for a better SE for these questions next time

Comment: Do you live in a baseball stadium? :)

Comment: Unless the lamp is right next to the supply, you'll need a lot of serious cabling to avoid voltage drop. You're really better of using proper mains powered LED floodlights.

Comment: look for server power supplies, they typically have larger current allowances per rail. if you pull 700W, you should have a 1050W PSU for full-time operation (50% overhead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you divide the power (700W) by the voltage (12V) that will give you the current.

So, 700/12=58.3A

This is **not** advisable on on molex connector - you need to think of something else.

Comment: To add a detail: the maximum rated current of a single pin on a standard molex connector (the 4 pin type) is 11 A, so the maximum you could get out of it is 22 A, but that is under a temperature rise of 30 K over ambient, which is quite a lot, so I would stay clear of that maximum rating.

Comment: @Arsenal seen too many of those plastic connectors that overheat and melt due to poor connections to have thought about mentioning the theoretical max...

Comment: I think it is good to have a feeling of how far off we actually are. I'd limit myself to 5 A, so we need at least 12 unmodified or 6 modified (for double 12 V) connectors.

Comment: Is the connector the only issue here?  Let's say I remove the connectors altogether and solder on a 14awg wire directly to the load -- can the rest of the PSU handle the load?

Comment: Now you ask a different question : will the psu run a max for 100% of the time? Then have you given it any cooling? When properly mounted in a case it has forced cooling...

Comment: @SolarMike Every computer PSU I've ever seen has its own fan. Computer builders aren't advised to run them at their maximum power, though. You could certainly *try* it but be prepared for a reduced lifetime.